# OpenCV does not work after installing it on my macOS. Can anyone help me out?

Tags: python, opencv

I installed OpenCV through Homebrew on my system and installed the `opencv-python` module through `pip`.

My code:

```py
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("image.png")
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The error it gives:

```sh
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.0) /tmp/opencv-20201123-26930-m95s1u/opencv-4.5.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

If I read through the documentation or look through other resources, I'm doing the same steps. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like normal behaviour for OpenCV. It is probably not finding an image `"image.png"`, make sure that the path `"image.png"` exists and can be read. You should be able to see what cv2 finds with `print(img)`, which should show as a numpy `ndarray`.